# Laravel Random Verify CSRF Token

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I currently have a web application in the process of being built in Laravel 5.3.

I have it running locally on my MacBook Pro using Laravel Valet with a SQL Server. All intended functionality works.

I then uploaded it up to my Ubuntu web server on DigitalOcean and have had it up there ever since I started this project ( 8 months ago ) without any issues.

For a specific form POST Request I am receiving a Token Mismatch Error:

```
TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68
```

The user is already logged in and other POST Requests on the application work. The form has the correct CSRF Token inside of the form and has the token stored in the head of the page under a meta tag (  ).

I am not having this issue locally and they both have the same Database Schema and Content.

I fail to understand why this issue would only happen on the web server.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: When you the token is correct "inside the form" do you mean an element of the form or the data sent? Do you have the form data and headers being sent and if so can you include them?

Comment: This is what I have inside of the form <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="...">

Comment: That looks right, are you sure that input is within and being submitted with the form? Sometimes browsers like Chrome will "organize" the DOM a bit if they don't like the format. The development tools of your favorite browser can help you track the actual request and see what's being sent.

Comment: Absolutely sure. Since all the pages are the same on my local version as the server I would think the page DOM is identical.

Comment: Does it happen every time? A token is only valid for 2 hours (by default, and by design), so you will get token mismatches if the form was left open for longer then that, and then submitted. I get this too.

Comment: It happens every time

Answer (score 1):

Based on my assumption: Make sure that you are added `$this->middleware('auth');` into the constructor of your controller which handle that post request.

Also try with use below one of the csrf token field option:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Or:

```
{{ csrf_field() }}
```

Comment: I already have had that middleware added to the constructor and have the 2nd csrf token field option inside my form. I am under the impression that the form wouldn't submit locally if I didn't correctly have the csrf token implemented.